# How to do exponential and logarithmic curve fitting in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, numpy, scipy, linear-regression

I have a set of data, and I want to compare which line describes it best (polynomials of different orders, exponential or logarithmic).
for example: a * np.exp(-b * x) + c

I solve the problem in python using `scipy.optimize import curve_fit` But I need to know how to solve this problem in C#. Is there any possible way to solve it?

This is my python program:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func_exp(x, a, b, c):
        #c = 0
        # return a * np.exp(b * x) + c
        return b * np.exp(c * x) + a

def exponential_regression (x_data, y_data):
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(func_exp, x_data, y_data, p0 = (0, 0, 0))
    print(popt)


x_data = np.array([1.36, 1.44, 1.41, 1.745, 2.25, 1.42, 1.45, 1.5, 1.58])
y_data = np.array([648, 618, 636,485, 384, 639, 630, 583, 529])
exponential_regression(x_data, y_data)
```

Comment: You need to use a library like .NET Numerics.

Comment: @RonBeyer .NET Numerics. has the same functionalities as python?